# Issue with listing application pool

Tags: batch-file, iis, iis-7.5

I was trying to list down application name and it's app pool and the script created which is listing almost all application details except few.   Some application pools are not getting listed down and some application showing duplicate entry.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list apppool "AppPoolName"
```

But this is showing a null value. The application listed in "Default Web Site" and almost all application details showing under this site except 2-3.
There's no error coming on which I can check.

Comment: That command only shows "application pools", and not "applications" under "sites". Make sure you know the basic concepts of IIS as that's mandate for any further discussions.

Comment: @LexLi I know that. Actually this command not showing the properties of "AppPoolName". If you know about IIS, this command will list "APPPOOL "PoolName" (MgdVersion:v4.0,MgdMode:Classic,state:Started)". But it is not showing anything.

Comment: You might run equivalent C# code to verify if this is an appcmd issue, or Microsoft.Web.Administration issue. Most likely you need to rebuild this server if IIS configuration system is corrupt.